# Fetch current and next row and compare in a loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, pdo, while-loop

I would like to compare two values from a table:

This is my table:

```
ID;VALUE
1;700
2;600
3;800
4;900
```

This is my query:

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT ID, VALUE FROM TABLE);
```

Now i like to compare the result of the current row with the next row. In mysql it was easy beacause i have to set the row number. I did not find any solution with PDO.

This is my code yet:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $id = $row["ID"];
      $val_current = $row["VALUE"];
      $row_next = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      $val_next = $row["VALUE"];
      if ($val_current > $val_next){
         echo "$id is greate!";
      }else{
         echo "$id is less!";
      }
}
```

The Result is:

```
1 is greater
3 is less
```

He missed to check the ID 2 agains ID 3 becaue i fetch the next element in the while loop. So i fetch it to get the next value and i fetch again in the loop. Can i reposition the cursor at the end of the loop?

Comment: Well, you can do **"compare current from previous"** also. store the current row, then when the next row comes, compare it, then overwrite. This will solve the some rows being skipped

Comment: Note that rows in SQL have no order, so if you want to compare next and previous, then you need to specify that order somewhere - either in the query, or the resulting array.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, this is straight-forward with window function [`lead()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lead):

```
select 
    t.*,
    (value - lead(value) over(order by id) > 0) is_greater
from mytable t
```

This gives you a boolean flag called `is_greater`, with following possible values:

- `1`: this value is greater than the next one
- `0`: this value is smaller than the next one
- `null`: there is no next value

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f7d058b672469a65ccab5cfdab2bfefc)**:

```
ID | VALUE | is_greater
-: | ----: | ---------:
 1 |   700 |          1
 2 |   600 |          0
 3 |   800 |          0
 4 |   900 |       null
```

In earlier versions, one option is to use a correlated subquery:

```
select 
    t.*,
    (value - (
        select t1.value 
        from mytable t1 
        where t1.id > t.id 
        order by t1.id limit 1
    ) > 0) is_greater
from mytable t
```

Comment: Greate but unfortanatly i am mysql 7

Comment: @user6625547: I updated my answer with a solution for earlier versions.

Comment: @user6625547 there is no such thing as mysql 7

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remember the previous row and use it in the next iteration pretending it's the current one, whereas the current row will serve as the next one.

```
$row = null;
while($row_next = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if ($row !== null)) {
        $id = $row["ID"];
        $val_current = $row["VALUE"];
        $val_next = $row_next["VALUE"];
        if ($val_current > $val_next){
            echo "$id is greater!";
        }else{
            echo "$id is less!";
        }
        echo "\n";
    }
    $row = $row_next;
}
```